# Query SQL table into a csv file and download it

Tags: php, sql, csv, pdo

I would like to query a table to a .csv file and automatically download it. The file is created with the appropriate data but the file that is downloaded displays wrong data.

```
$filename = 'file.csv';
$i=0;
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DATE, TYPE, AMOUNT, BALANCE FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE USERNAME=? ORDER BY DATE ASC");
        $stmt->execute(array($user));
        $num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

        $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+')  or die("can't open file");
        fputcsv($handle, array('Date','Type','Amount','Balance'));
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $row2[$i][0] = $row['DATE'];
            $row2[$i][1] = $row['TYPE'];
            $row2[$i][2] = $row['AMOUNT'];
            $row2[$i][3] = $row['BALANCE'];
            $i++;
            echo $i;
            fputcsv($handle, array($row['DATE'], $row['TYPE'], $row['AMOUNT'], $row['BALANCE']));
        }

        fclose($handle);
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
        header("Connection: close");
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
    }
```

This is how the file looks like when it is downloaded in my browser:
[image]

Sometimes it looks like this:
[image]

And this is how it looks like when it is created on the server:
[image]

**The file that is created on the server always contain the appropriate structure and data. The file that is downloaded for the user is different and wrong for some reason.**

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Please, extract certain part of your problem. What does PDO to do with it for example?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean? I use PDO to query the table

Comment: There is some obvious weirdness going on in your broken excel file (look at the doctype) that isn't visible in your script.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Specifically, "header already sent"? That Doctype and subsequent html has me questioning if you need to suppress your template and/or layout depending on which CMS or template engine you're using. This being executed in the controller I assume?

Comment: Thank you guys all for your efforts. I hope this complete example will be useful for other developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed

```
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+')  or die("can't open file");
```

instead of

```
$handle = fopen("php://output", "w");
```